# What does "The policies are designed to cover inadvertence and negligence." mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does "The policies are designed to cover inadvertence and negligence." mean?
Inadvertence usually means the quality of being not intentional.
Does it mean that the policies are well designed so that people unintentionally violating the policies will not be penalized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is saying that the (insurance) policies will compensate the holder/s in the event that damage/harm results from the holder's lack of awareness/knowledge or his/her failure to take necessary care / do necessary maintenance.

In practice most insurance policies are likely to state that they will NOT cover the holder under these circumstances.

Comment: That depends on the type of policy. But all policies will exclude such acts committed intentionally *by the policyholder*.